# Does CrystalReports have diagnostic logging? Certain fields won't show up when printed

Tags: debugging, crystal-reports

I am using the Crystal Reports that comes with Visual Studio 2008

Here is my problem. I have a simple little command line utility that generates a single crystal report. It

1. Connects to a database
2. Gets a dataset out of a stored procedure. The dataset is always one table with one row.
3. Sets the dataset as the report's DataSource
4. Depending on command-line flags either prints to the default printer, emails, or saves the report as a pdf

The app is used something like this:

```
c:\> GenerateReport 1000 1345 1 email=me@somewhere.com pdf=c:\temp\ print
```

Where the first 3 arguments specify parameters for the stored procedure and the other arguments are optional but tell the utility what to do with the report. Very simple stuff. Works great, and has been for some time.

Except that since upgrading crystal reports (from whichever version was with vs2003) its been a little wonky. ONLY on the production site and ONLY when the report is printed, several (but not all) of the fields on the report are left blank!

This is especially confounding because the report is instantiated only once and all the data on report is coming from the DataSet - I have no report parameter fields. And the dataset is fetched and set as the datasource only once at the application start. After that I am simply calling report.PrintToPrinter, report.Export, or report.ExportToStream on the same instance depending on whether I want to print, export or email respectively.

What this means is that if I run the utility with the print and email=me@mycompany options the email that I get and the report that is printed are from the EXACT SAME ReportClass instance. Yet the same values that are consistently missing when printed are visible when the report is emailed or saved to disk.

Even worse, I can take the exact same executable. Move it to my development computer, point the config file at the production database and it prints to my local printer with all the values filled in!

I'm really quite stumped as to how to investigate this further - it seems like something is going on inside of CrystalReports. Is there some sort of diagnostic mode or logging mode that I can turn on that might give me a clue how to fix this?

Comment: what happens if you print before exporting? or is that the order already?

Comment: Its kinda a pain in the ass since it only happens in one production system in an unmanned shack in the middle of the desert in new mexico.  Basically I have to have someone go over there, check the print outs, and then scan and fax them over.  But I've tried it locally with all manner of combinations - always works locally

Answer (score 1):

To first of all answer your question, NO, there is no diagnostics logging, other than what you see from the report and any exceptions that arise.

As for what might be wrong, if the problem ONLY occurs when it's printed, it HAS to be related to printer drivers and/or fonts. It can not be anything else. For a for-sure way to fix the report to print on the production printer... install Crystal Reports on the computer that has the production printer installed and open/format/test/save the report against that SPECIFIC printer. That will fix the issue. And of course, remove Crystal Reports when you are done fixing the report.

If the report is running fine and the output is incorrect in terms of what gets printed, and no other errors happen, it HAS to be a compatibility issue with the printer. Nothing else.